# How to iterate multiple enumerables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I know two arrays can be zipped and the result can be iterated with #each. But how do you do it with an unknown number of enumerables?
Let's say

```
anand = %w(1-0 0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.0)
carlsen = %w(0-1 0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.0)
kramnik = %w(0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.0)
players= [anand, carlsen, kramnik]
#something smart

players.each{|round|puts round} #first line should be  "1-0 0-1 0.5-0.5"
```

Comment: Why can't you use a while loop and a plain old index variable?

Comment: @HamishGrubijan: Because using while-loops is more error prone and more verbose than using plain old higher-order functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
players.transpose.map {|a| a.join(" ")}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
anand.zip(carlsen, kramnik) do |round| puts round.join(" ") end
```

This will print:

```
1-0 0-1 0.5-0.5
0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5
0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5 0.5-0.5
1.0 1.0 1.0
```